# Expanding selected row in gridview on WEH8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-embedded-8.1

I am currently developing an application for Windows Embedded Handheld 8.1 and have run into an issue where I have a dynamically expanding grid inside a gridview. My problem  is that since this application runs on handheld devices I have a very limited space to use on every row.

What I would like to do is to just show general information on each row and then when a row is tapped or selected in the device, I would like to somehow expand that specific row and show some more detailed information, this seems to be problematic however since as soon as I start messing with a specific rows height, every other row in the ItemTemplate naturally also grows, leaving a lot of blank spaces in the grid.

Normally I would have used a DataGrid and DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate, but that control does not seem to be implemented in WEH8.1.

So my question is if someone has a solution or possibly a workaround to my problem?

Code Example on GridView Below:

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">

        <GridView x:Name="gvCustomerOrderRows">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="{Binding BackgroundColor}" Margin="0" Height="{Binding ShowSecondRowHeight}"  Tapped="Grid_Tapped"  Tag="{Binding kor_row}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="31.25"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="58.75"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="105"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding kor_pos}" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityHideThenText}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,17,0,16"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding kor_partno}" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityHideThenText}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,17,0,16"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding kor_txt}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" MaxLines="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding kor_rqty}" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityHideThenText}" Grid.Column="5" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtQuantity" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding rep_qty, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityHideThenText}" Background="{Binding DeliverColor, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="{Binding DeliverColor, Mode=TwoWay}" InputScope="Number" TextAlignment="Right"  Grid.Column="6" GotFocus="txtQuantity_GotFocus" Margin="6,10,-1,0" Height="39"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding kor_ldat}" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityHideThenText}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="Stock Loc.:  " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityHideThenText}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityHideThenText}" Tag="{Binding kor_row}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped" Margin="10,0,0,0"><Underline><Run Text="{Binding SelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay}"/> </Underline></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocQuantity}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityHideThenText}" FontSize="14"  TextAlignment="Center"/>

                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>

            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </ScrollViewer>
```